What, if anything, is this metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ named? And, what do the open balls in this metric space geometrically look like?
For each $\mathbf{x} := \left( \xi_1, \xi_2 \right) \in \mathbf{R}^2$, let
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert := \sqrt{ \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 }.
$$
And, for any pair of points $\mathbf{x} := \left( \xi_1, \xi_2 \right)$ and $\mathbf{y} := \left( \eta_1, \eta_2 \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let
$$
d ( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} ) := \begin{cases} \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert + \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert = \sqrt{ \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 } + \sqrt{ \eta_1^2 + \eta_2^2 } & \mbox{ if } \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \neq \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert, \mbox{ that is if } \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2  \neq \eta_1^2 + \eta_2^2,  \\ \lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \rVert = \sqrt{ \left( \xi_1 - \eta_1 \right)^2 + \left( \xi_2 - \eta_2 \right)^2  } & \mbox{ if } \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert = \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert, \mbox{ that is if } \xi_1^2 + \xi_2^2 = \eta_1^2 + \eta_2^2.     \end{cases} 
$$
While I can show that this function $d \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow [0, +\infty)$ is a metric, I am not sure how to visualise the shapes of the open balls in this particular metric space.
If $\mathbf{c} := (0, 0)$, then for any $r > 0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
B_d ( \mathbf{c} ; r ) &= \left\{ (\alpha, \beta ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon d \big( (\alpha, \beta ), \, \mathbf{c} \big) < r \right\} \\
&= \left\{ (\alpha, \beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon 0 \leq \alpha^2+ \beta^2 < r^2 \right\}  \\
&= \cdots. 
\end{align}
$$
If $\mathbf{c} := ( \lambda, \mu ) \neq (0, 0)$, then what? What do the open balls centered at $\mathbf{c}$ and of radius $r > 0$ look like?

It is sometimes called the French-railway metric, or SNCF metric, because to go from one point to another point not on the same line, you must pass through the origin first. This is a quite accurate analogy, when the origin is thought of as Paris. You will find numerous questions about this metric on MSE with those key words

@Didier This is not quite the French railway metric. Here the special case happens if two points are distinct but have the same distance to the origin, not if they lie on the same line to the origin.

@quarague You're right, I misread the conditions, my bad!

In general, you have three cases.
If $r < ||c||$ then $B_d(c,r)$ just consist of a small segment of the circle around $0$ with radius $||c||$ centered on $c$.
If $||c|| < r < 2\cdot ||c||$ then $B_d(c,r)$ will consist of a bigger segment of the circle around $0$ with radius $||c||$ plus a disk around $0$ with radius $r - ||c||$. Note that the ball is disconnected.
If $r > 2\cdot ||c||$ then $B_d(c,r)$ will be a disk around $0$ with radius $r - ||c||$.
